# Why do all of the new files I make in a GitHub repository go to the .gitnore file?

Tags: github

In my github repository, I'm making new files and folders. I recently found out that the reason github desktop isnt showing them is because they keep going into the .gitnore. I keep having to force add it with git bash and its super annoying. can someone please help me?

I tried this with a different repository and the some thing happened. I reinstalled github desktop but it kept happening.

Comment: What do you mean by "they go into the .gitignore"? Can you provide some details here to make this clear - give an example of what you do and what is the result.

Comment: Also adding the relevant portion of your `.gitignore` files and the output of `ls` from your repo root would be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a new file (that you would end up having to do a git add --force), try first (`before` adding it):

```
cd /path/to/repository
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/file
```

That way, you will *know* what `.gitignore` (or global exclude file) is behind your current predicament.
You can then edit that file, and make sure its rules don't prevent the files you need to be added to your  project.